# Why null key change value to 1 in php array?

Tags: php, arrays, null, boolean

Following is the code I am testing -

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$myarr = array(NULL => "swapnesh", TRUE => 1, 4 => "swap", "swap" => 4, TRUE => NULL, NULL => TRUE );
echo "<pre>";
//var_dump($myarr);
print_r($myarr);
echo count($myarr);
```

This code outputs -

```
Array
(
    [] => 1
    [1] => 
    [4] => swap
    [swap] => 4
)
4
```

Concerns/queries regarding the code -

1. Why NULL as a key change value to 1 (at first index) I can consider a scenario when someone may suggest since NULL as a key is used twice so value overwritten but I checked it with FALSE so it must output 0 but no value output in this case.
2. At second value 1 is blank however it was supposed to be 1.
3. Count is 4 what I was thinking of either 5 or 6 but for 4 I am not sure how it is as last two values skipped.

Search involved before asking -

On php net I checked the doc and found this is something related but cant figured out much in my case.
Link - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

**EDIT**  For the 3rd point I believe TRUE & NULL is used twice so ie its outputting 4 however let me know if it is exactly the case or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `print_r`, it makes your output readable so:

1. NULL key is overwritten from `"swapnesh"` to `true`, printable representation of `true` is 1
2. `NULL` and `false` does not produce output in printable format.
3. Count is 4 because you are overwriting 2 keys.

To get better output of variables, use `var_dump`

Comment: thanks for the explanation..i was close with the 3rd point but really cant able to grasp anything about point 1 & 2

Answer (score 1):

> Why NULL as a key change value to 1 (at first index) I can consider a scenario when someone may suggest since NULL as a key is used twice so value overwritten but I checked it with FALSE so it must output 0 but no value output in this case.

PHP prints the boolean FALSE as an empty string. Typecast it into an int to get '0'.

> At second value 1 is blank however it was supposed to be 1.

TRUE is used as a key twice also, so its value is getting overwritten to NULL, which prints as empty string.

> Count is 4 what I was thinking of either 5 or 6 but for 4 I am not sure how it is as last two values skipped.

Your count is lower because your last two values in the array are overwriting existing values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`null` and `true` are not valid keys. Keys can be either strings or integers. `null` and `true` are cast to an empty string and `1` respectively, which means you have several empty string/`1` keys which overwrite each other.

If you want automatically indexed keys, leave the key off:

```
$myarr = array("swapnesh", 1, 4 => "swap", "swap" => 4, null, true);
```